# Why does this LCD Bias Driver Have a Fault Mode?

Tags: embedded, lcd

I have a product that uses a [TPS65150](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65150.pdf) LCD bias driver. I recently had an issue with a batch of boards, where this driver would go into fault mode (low on FDLY pin).

The fault mode is triggered on a time delay if the output voltages are not in range. The time is set by a capacitor connected to FLDY. Once a fault occurs, according to the datasheet the only fix is a full power cycle.

I checked the output voltages on a scope, and they rise nicely and don't really overshoot. Since it seemed safe, I disabled that feature and now the board works fine.

So here's my question. Why have this feature at all? It causes a hard fault. The only situation I can think of where that's a *good* outcome, is if the alternative is burning something out. As a result I'm wary of just disabling the feature and moving on.

Is that the case? Ie. is it a bad idea to just disable the fault mode?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is best to shut down when voltages are not within specs.

Even your desktop PC has that feature in the power supply to protect all the components from overvoltage damage or undervoltage causing unexpected behaviour and malfunctioning system.

The chip will go into shutdown if there are problems on the input voltage, or output voltages.

LCD displays may not be that easily damaged immediately, but exposing it to incorrect bias voltages will degrade it in the long term, as there should be no DC bias applied on the LCD segments.

Therefore it makes sense to signal the user immediately about a problem. In a system with some kind of other control, it could detect the fault condition from the chip and try to restart it if possible.

The other option is that if not all voltages are within specs, the display will degrade faster and user is not indicated about a problem driving the display.