# What might cause light vertical banding on LCD?

Tags: lcd

I'm troubleshooting a PCB which uses a STM32 to drive a [large LCD](https://www.buydisplay.com/download/manual/ER-TFT070-6_Datasheet.pdf). I have 2 versions. The new version has light green vertical banding on the display. The old one does not.

[image: LCD vertical banding]

[image: LCD vertical banding2]

I'm using the same display and firmware to test both boards. This leads me to believe it's an electrical issue.

I initially had a [problem with the bias driver going into fault mode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696131/why-does-this-lcd-bias-driver-have-a-fault-mode), so  a problem with the bias supply is my first guess. Unfortunately all the bias voltages look dead on with no visible noise on my 50MHz oscilloscope.

Any idea what might be causing this? Or what to check?

The banding is most visible in areas of the image which are gray.

I didn't change the bias driver at between the 2 versions. I did add some EMC stuff to the backlight driver, but I don't see anyway it could cause this effect if it was malfunctioning.

**Edit:** I tried bypassing the backlight driver, and running the backlight from an external supply. That did not fix the banding.

Comment: You have a display with RGB interface. If there is a problem in the green colour, have you checked the connections for green data? Or for all data pins, because it might look greener because there are problems with blue and red data pins that make the image greener.

Comment: @Justme Just checked. The traces and soldering between the STM32 and the LCD connector look good.

Comment: OK, is the connector making good contact? Any damage on cable? Does the problem follow display or MCU?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, but are you seeing more green than you expect or less red and blue?

Comment: The color overall looks fine. All the light gray and white looks perfect. It's more like a noise issue. There's a slight shimmer to the pixels that isn't present when driven by the other PCB.

Comment: @Justme The problem follows the MCU. I only have 1 display.

Comment: Is the dot clock polarity correct? Are setup and hold times achieved? Are data wires approximately equal in length with clock and sync wires?

Comment: @Justme I could double check, but why would one PCB work and another not if that was the issue? The layout and pin connections between the LCD and MCU are identical for the 2 boards.

Comment: @Drew If the timings are marginal then one board may work fine because it is within the margin and one board may not work if it is outside the margin. The boards and the microcontrollers are not identical, they have manufacturing tolerances. Try putting a finger or scope probe to data, clock or sync lines, this will add a slight amount of resistance and capacitance and will cause a slight delay. If you see any change for better or worse then you know something is wrong, like wrong data clock edge, or some data lines too fast or slow compared to clock.

Comment: @Justme Good idea. Touching that area has no effect however.

Comment: Nothing seems to disturb the positions or opacity of the bands.

Comment: Are the bands constant or flickering? Also, do you see those on the section you have posted or across the entire display?

Comment: They are constant. Hard to say what would happen if part of the screen was not written, because the whole buffer is stored inside the MCU. If I don't initialize it, it will contain random noise even if functioning correctly.